# Easy clarification for the question 'show that $x^3-2x^2+6x+6$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$'

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory

I successfully completed this question by showing it was irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}_5$.  I showed this by putting each of the elements of $\mathbb{Z}_5$ into the polynomial.

My question is this: in the mark scheme, they checked $f(1)$,$f(2)$,$f(4)$ and $f(5)$, but didn't bother checking $f(3)$, (if we call the polynomial $f(x)$).  Do you think this was a mistake or is there some reason that $f(3)$ doesn't need to be checked?

It's a minor confusion, but one that I would like to understand if there is anything to be understood about it.  I hope I'm not overlooking something obvious.

Thanks

Comment: I think it was an accidental omission. Also, instead of $f(5)$, I would have checked $f(0)$ instead (simpler, and of course, equivalent).

Comment: @quasi Great, thanks for clearing that up.  I thought I was missing something obvious!

Comment: The title mentions mod $n$ so why do you choose $n = 5?\ $ Typo? Or maybe you mean *some* $n?\ $ Please try to be more precise.

Comment: That should be just $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: You can also apply Eisenstein's Criterion to show that $f$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}$ (or over $\mathbb{Q}$), using the prime $p=2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a mistake and $f(3)$ should be checked.  Thanks to Quasi